# using jq to merge two json values based on key value

Tags: json, file, merge, jq, key-value

i have two json files that i would like to merge based on the value of a key. the key name is different in both json files but the value would be the same. i am using jq to try to get this done. most of the examples i have found all merge based on key name and not value.

**sample1.json**

```
 [
  {
    "unique_id": "pp1234",
    "unique_id_type": "netid",
    "rfid": "12245556890478",
 },
{
    "unique_id": "aqe123",
    "unique_id_type": "netid",
    "rfid": "12234556890478",
 }
]
```

**sample2.json**

```
[
 {
 "mailing_state": "New York",
  "mobile_phone_number": "(982) 2541212",
  "netid": "pp1234",
  "netid_reachable": "Y",
 },
 {
 "mailing_state": "New York",
  "mobile_phone_number": "(982) 5551212",
  "netid": "aqe123",
  "netid_reachable": "Y",
 }
]
```

i would want the output to look something like:

**results.json**

```
 [
      {
        "unique_id": "pp1234",
        "unique_id_type": "netid",
        "rfid": "12245556890478",
        "mailing_state": "New York",
        "mobile_phone_number": "(982) 2541212",
        "netid_reachable": "Y",
     },
     {
        "unique_id": "aqe123",
        "unique_id_type": "netid",
        "rfid": "12234556890478",
        "mailing_state": "New York",
        "mobile_phone_number": "(982) 5551212",
        "netid_reachable": "Y",
    }
]
```

order of results would not matter as long as the records are merged based on netid/unique_id keys. i am open to using something other than jq if necessary. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix the JSON (e.g. run `jq empty data.json` to see the points of failure, or use jsonlint.com).  Also, the output that is said to be expected does not match the input files. 
 Finally, since SO is not a free programming service, please show at least one of your attempts to solve the problem.  You might find it helpful to review the guidelines at [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the sample input files have been corrected, the following invocation should do the trick:

```
jq --argfile uid sample1.json '
  ($uid | INDEX(.unique_id)) as $dict
  | map( $dict[.netid] + del(.netid) )
' sample2.json
```

If you prefer not to use --argfile because it has been deprecated, you could (for example) use --slurpfile and change `$uid` in the jq program to `$uid[0]`.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. i tried using the syntax provided and it merged the second record but not the first for some reason. ( i also fixed the incorrect unique_id in the original example.)

Comment: Did you fix the input files?  I have verified that after fixing them, the invocation as shown produces results.json.